# Run-Time Check Failure #0 Occur when I call the IHTMLDocument3::getElememntById function in MFC

Tags: mfc

This is the code I write in a OnBtnClick Function

```
CComPtr<IHTMLDocument3> pDoc3 = (IHTMLDocument3 *)m_webBrowser.get_Document();
CComPtr<IHTMLElement> pElem;
BSTR idTmp = CComBSTR(L"article_summary");
HRESULT hr = pDoc3->getElementById(idTmp, &pElem);
```

I'm trying to get the element which Id is "article_sumary"。。。but I got this

```
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function
call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling
convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first cast you have looks nasty. I would get the non-casted document type (IHTMLDocument2 ?) and then perform a query interface on it to the the IHTMLDocument3.

```
CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> pDoc2 = m_webBrowser.get_Document();// assuming it returns IHTMLDocument2

CComPtr<IHTMLDocument3> pDoc3;
pDoc2->QueryInterface(&pDoc3);
```

Comment: wow, that's exactly what I just done. I read the Essntial COM and then change my code。。。I'm just a beginer of COM. The Run-Time Check Failure #0 mislead me for two day!!!